# error CS0619 & error CS1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am watching a tutorial where it seems to work, but in my case, I am getting these errors:

> error CS0619: `UnityEngine.Component.renderer' is obsolete:`Property
>   renderer has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead.
>   (UnityUpgradable)'

and:

> error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a
>   definition for`material' and no extension method `material' of type`
>   UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?).

Here's the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ScrollScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 0;

    void Update () {
        renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (Time.time * speed, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about "Property renderer has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead."?

Answer (score 0):

public Renderer render;

void Start(){

render = this.GetComponent "<"Renderer">"();

}

dont use quotation marks